# Accessing custom http response headers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-http

[image: Response from server]

I am trying to access the header 'error-detail' as you can see in the browser network inspector (link above), the header gets returned. Server-wise I have also added the custom header to the 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' to allow cross-domain requests as this was suggested to be the fix on other questions.

Below is the request to the server along with the success/error callbacks.

```
this.signon = function (request, onComplete, onError) {
    console.log("Calling server with 'login' request...");

    return $http.post("http://localhost:8080/markit-war/services/rest/UserService/login/", request)
        .then(onComplete, onError);
};

var onLookupComplete = function(response) {
    if (response.data.username)
    {
        //If user is returned, redirect to the dashboard.
        $location.path('/dashboard');
    }

    $scope.username = response.data.username;
};

var onError = function(response) {
    $scope.error = "Ooops, something went wrong..";
    console.log('error-detail: ' + response.headers('error-detail'));
};
```

When I try access the response header as seen below:

```
    console.log(response.headers());
    console.log('error-detail: ' + response.headers('error-detail'));
```

This only outputs:
content-type: "application/json"
error-detail: null

Is there a reason why the error-detail header is not being mapped over to the response object?

Comment: can you do response.headers().error-detail ?

Comment: @user2085143 Nope, surely that isn't legal syntax is it?

Comment: Probably not, but not sure what response.headers() actually returns. Have you taken a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: Can you post the angular code that you are using to make the request, as well as the callback function?

Comment: @LarryTurtis Have edited my question to include the request + callback as requested. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. To have access to custom headers, your server needs to set this special `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, otherwise your browser will only allow access to 6 predefined header values as listed in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

In your screenshot such a header is not present in the response. You should have a look at the backend for this cors header to also be present in the response.

Answer (score 9):

This is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) Issue. Because this is a cross-origin request, the browser is hiding most ot the headers. The server needs to include a [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header in its response.

The [Access-Control-Expose-Headers<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) response header indicates which headers can be exposed as part of the response by listing their names.

By default, only the 6 simple response headers are exposed:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to list them using the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

For more information, see [MDN HTTP Header -- Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)